# How to check class of multiple class elements in javascript, without jquery

Tags: javascript

I have the following javascript code to put the uploader name before the upload date and view count in youtube search results.

```
function hasClass(element, cls) {
    return (' ' + element.className + ' ').indexOf(' ' + cls + ' ') > -1;
}
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('yt-lockup-meta-info');
var elemss = document.getElementsByClassName('yt-uix-sessionlink g-hovercard spf-link');
var elemsss = 1;
var elemssss = 0;
var myElem = document.getElementById('sb-button-notify');
if (myElem == null) elemsss = 0; // these two lines are here to skip the additional element
                                 // that is only there if you are logged in
for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; ++i) {
  if (hasClass(elemss[i+elemsss],'yt-uix-tile-link'))
    {elemssss=elemssss+1;elemsss=elemsss+3;alert('damn');}
elems[i+elemssss].insertBefore(elemss[i+elemsss],elems[i+elemssss].firstChild);}
```

Instead of the hasClass function, how can I check the whole class attribute of a multiple class element? This didn't work:

```
element.className=='yt-uix-sessionlink yt-uix-tile-link 
                    yt-ui-ellipsis yt-ui-ellipsis-2 g-hovercard spf-link'
```

I just need to check the class, so the code can skip elements with a specific class. An even better solution would be an alternative to document.getElementsByClassName, which would only get elements with exactly the given classes, and ignore ones that have MORE classes.

Answer (score 3):

```
element.classList
```

It would return you the array of all the classes present on the element
like `["site-icon", "favicon", "favicon-stackoverflow"]` , so then by using normal javascript you can implement hasClass functionality of your own.

So your hasClass function becomes

```
function hasClass(element, cls){
  return element.classList.contains(cls);
}
```

Comment: why downvote.. atleast put a comment so that I could also understand

Comment: so, to check the third class for example, i could use var cl = element.classList; if(cl[3]=='class'){*do something*}?

Comment: yes.. once you have the array of all class names of element you can search the array for your required class.. did you downvote? If yes may I know why?

Comment: i didnt, but i upvoted now. its not "publicly visible" though as i dont have enough reputation

Comment: Btw, [`element.classList` currently has somewhat poor support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=classlist)

Comment: @vinayakj For what it's worth, your answer looks fine to me and I upvoted it.

Comment: @TinyGiant Working in everything except IE9 seems like decent support to me, and you can always [shim it to work with IE7, 8, and 9](https://github.com/eligrey/classList.js/)

Comment: @TinyGiant OP used `getElementsByClassName` and `classList` is also have almost same support So I have suggested that approach..

Comment: isnt there any other way to check exact matches in classes?

Comment: you have the className List and you have the exact classes so just compare them with `length` properrty and `contains` function.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `classList` but this is not supported in all browsers.

I think the best solution is something like that:

```
function hasClass (element, cls) {
    var classes = element.className.split(' ');
    return classes.indexOf(cls) != -1;
}
```