# How to check if an element has multiple classes with vanilla JS

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to figure out how to write an if statement that works something like this:

```
if (element contains class 1 && class 2) {
   // do this
}
```

How do I write that if statement to check for multiple classes?

Is there a way to make the .contains method check for more than one class?

***What I've found so far:***

[How to check class of multiple class elements in javascript, without jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31438051/how-to-check-class-of-multiple-class-elements-in-javascript-without-jquery)

Problem is, it seems to be returning an array of all the classes that the element contains, which is not what I want. I need the function to check if the element contains the classes that I am supplying it with.

One of the solutions looks to me like it's asking us to create our own function to do this, but is there a native method on JS which will do the trick?

I'm quite new to this stuff and I really appreciate the patience you guys have shown in answering my questions.

Comment: although `matches` is the answer, if  element.classList returns all the classes of an element, how hard is it to compare it to a list of classes you are supplying? it's programming 101.

Comment: You're absolutely right of course, I was just looking to see if there was a quicker way to do it in future since I think I will be using this a good number of times :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use the `.matches()` API on the element, and it's pretty well-supported now:

```
if (element.matches(".class1.class2")) ...
```

It's like a built-in version of jQuery `.is()`.

[Documentation link.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches)

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for, thank you very much! :)

Comment: Good solution, even though I kind of dislike the need for a string builder here. How does your approach fare with class names containing a `.`?

Comment: @connexo I *think* the API allows them to be quoted with backslash like the jQuery one does, or if not you'd do it the same way as in a CSS file, by using some other sort of escape.

Comment: No need for trickery like that with my approach. Just do `[...element.classList].contains('a', 'c.d')`, see my answer below. I know modifying built-in objects is risky and questionable, but elegant as well.

Comment: @connexo there's always more than one way to do something like this in the front-end world :)

Comment: Sure, but eliminating string building and thus, escaping, from the equation makes it alot more robust and simple.

Comment: @connexo yes if starting from an array of class names an operation using `.classList` is probably less trouble.

Answer (score 3):

Put the class names you want to test for into an array, then use `Array.prototype.every()` to check if all members of your array exist in the element's `classList`:

```js
console.log(['a', 'b'].every(e=>div.classList.contains(e)))
console.log(['a', 'b', 'c'].every(e=>div.classList.contains(e)))
```

```html
<div class="a b" id="div"></div>
```

Unfortunately `Element.classList` is read-only, so you cannot add anything to its prototype. You can however do that on the `Array.prototype`:

```js
Array.prototype.contains = function(...args) { 
  return [...args].every(c=>this.includes(c))
}

console.log([...div.classList].contains('a', 'b'))
console.log([...div.classList].contains('a', 'c'))
console.log([...div.classList].contains('a', 'c.d'))
```

```html
<div class="a b c.d" id="div"></div>
```

**Important:** Please note that this violates the basic OOP rule *Do not modify objects you don't own.* As such, it would be better to create a named function taking the element and an array with a list of classes to test for.

Answer (score -2):

There is a native API for the browser that lets you play with the DOM. jQuery is not always needed. https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_element_classlist.asp.

You can use the 'classList.contains' method

```
document.getElementById({id}).classList.contains({class}) -- returns true or flase
```

Comment: Read again: *Is there a way to make the `.contains` method check for **more than one** class?*

Comment: my apologies... you can get an array of classes u want to check against and you iterate over it with 'contains' you can this looks like a good example below.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6391448/how-to-apply-an-array-of-classes-to-classlist-contains

Comment: Then yes it's not answering the question anymore ..